# Are query objects in SqlAlchemy immutable?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Let's say I got a query like this ...

```
baseQuery = MyDbObj.query.filter_by(someProp='foo')
```

If, at a later point, I extend that query with something else (let's say, another filter) ...

```
derivedQuery = baseQuery.filter_by(anotherProp='bar')
```

will this result in the original query be modified, internally, or is a new query instance created?

**Background:** My use case is that I got multiple cases that only differ in one filter. Right now there is a ton of copy pasted query code (not my fault, I inherited this codebase) which I am cleaning up. For the cases where only one query is ultimately executed, I don't care if the original query gets modified. However I also have cases where two queries are executed, so here it matters that I can extend two queries from a base-query without them interfering with each other.

Though maybe a solution here could be to do that filtering in python itself, and not making two queries against the DB in the first place (I will keep that as a 2nd option).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLAlchemy creates a copy when filtering. So when you do

```
derivedQuery = baseQuery.filter_by(anotherProp='bar')
```

then `derivedQuery` is a copy of `baseQuery` with the filter applied. See the [docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.filter_by) for more details.

Comment: Ah, thanks for pointing that out. So I can actually do it like I want, thats good news :)